# how can I test the result of "dynamic_cast" without causing segment fault

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm writing a class using both polymorphism and template, it's like:

```cpp
class base {
    virtual ~base() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class derived : public base {
T a;
    void save(T a_) { a = a_; }
};
```

so when I wanna use function `derived::save()`, basicly, I need `dynamic_cast`, but it cannot check if it's a good cast or a bad one:

```cpp
void test() {
    base *p = new derived<float>();
    // good case
    dynamic_cast<derived<float>*>(p)->save(1);
    // bad case
    dynamic_cast<derived<int>*>(p)->save(1);
}
```

As you can see, the good case works fine, but the bad one would cause a segment fault which is kind of difficult to locate in a large project.

So, is there any way I check the `cast`, and warn the user like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class derived : public base {
T a;
using type = T;
/// of course this would not work, but you know want I mean
    void save(T a_) {
        if (std::is_same< std::decltype(a_), type >::value)
            a = a_;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid type");
    }
};
```

Comment: Store the result of `dynamic_cast` in a variable, and check for `nullptr`? Or cast to a *reference* which will throw an exception on error (e.g. `dynamic_cast<derived<T>&>(*p)`)?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer if the cast is unsuccessful, perhaps you want to check that. Regardless, if you need a dynamic_cast, your design is probably broken.

Comment: `std::variant<int, float>` could be an alternative here that does not rely on polymorphism...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check result of the dynamic cast:

```
void test() {
    base* p = new derived<float>();
    // good case
    if (auto* d = dynamic_cast<derived<float>*>(p))
         d->save(1); // called
    if (auto* d = dynamic_cast<derived<int>*>(p))
         d->save(1); // not called
    delete p;
}
```

Making `save` virtual in the base class seems better BTW.

Comment: thx, it works.but `save` takes different types of argument (which I don't know what they might be), so I cannot make it a virtual function